# what file systems are compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: disk-formatting

I  am looking at buying a large (2TB or larger) external drive for backups and want to know which file formats are supported on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Alternatively if you know of a drive that is compatible out of the box, it would be helpful

Comment: you should check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained

Comment: Have you considered a Dropbox subscription? Dropbox integrates very well with Ubuntu "out of the box" and your files will be safer off site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need read/write access to this drive from Ubuntu and also Windows, then I believe you are still best to format in ntfs.

Answer (score 3):

If the external drive will be used only by Ubuntu, then stick with the file system you use on the host machine, whether it’s `ext4`, `Btrfs`, or `zfs`. Ubuntu supports a lot of file systems for compatibility reasons, but sticking with something that is Linux-specific will save headaches in the future.